# adobe muse Auto moving images

Tags: adobe, muse

I would like to get all images, logos and text to always fit the screen. ie i view this on my pc and the site i see will be resized to fit my tv (screens a lot bigger)

There is a few things

1, No css code. Although i am sure it is possible with css but I know this will be possible using the tools provided just not sure how.
2, Be strait forward and not to complicated (if possible). I'm not that great with muse yet and come from just writing out the code.

Answer (score 0):

First place a rectangular shape then fill it with the image you want to use... just resize the rectangular shape then...their will be a tooltip that would appear, the width and height of your image... just make the width 100%

to view the sample image just open the link below

> [https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10378250_933301960022761_4004009316023420430_n.jpg?oh=32675100ced7bafcd60a175fda3c93e3&oe=54E39025&**gda**=1424210970_f0641f29deca2c42c99251330aeb33c2](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10378250_933301960022761_4004009316023420430_n.jpg?oh=32675100ced7bafcd60a175fda3c93e3&oe=54E39025&__gda__=1424210970_f0641f29deca2c42c99251330aeb33c2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply man but i do not seem to get any tool tip pop up. i tried hovering over the image and nothing showed. i then checked the window bit and looked through to see if anything was unchecked but couldn't find anything for hight and with (not counting the change the literal size of the image)

http://imgur.com/fV5UmL2
Theres a pic of my page, hopefully you can see what i am missing.

Comment: also did double click the image too.

Comment: do not just place the images. Place a rectangular shape first then fill it with an image... well done! hope it could help

Comment: if the tooltip did not appear... just resize it... till it touch the sides of your canvas

I am using the latest adobe muse